See more than just the first compiler error in VS Code? (Or a different IDE?)
In a project, there may be multiple lines of code that could cause errors. When using VS Code, the editor typically stops at the first encountered error and highlights it, preventing subsequent errors from being shown until the first one is addressed. I would prefer a solution where all errors in the code are displayed at once, instead of stopping after the first one. Are there any alternatives to VS Code, or perhaps extensions or tools that can achieve this behavior?
I attempted to adjust the settings, but to no avail.

if your compiler stops at the first error your problem matcher can't show other possible errors

I am working on a project and need to identify all potential errors during execution, rather than stopping at the first one. If no tools currently offer this feature, I'm considering modifying the VS Code source code. Could you suggest which files in VS Code control execution flow or error handling? Alternatively, are there any editors that already provide this feature

how can you run/execute when you have compiler errors. Why not fix the first error and then run the compiler again to get the next first error. What you might need is a linter for your language.
